# can't use pgxml_xpath

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1, I thought it was supposed to support this XML integration but I can't get it to work.  I try this query:

```
select data from ddm_table_data order by pgxml_xpath(data, '//xmltest/col1/text()', '', '');
```

And it comes up with the following errors:

```
ERROR: function pgxml_xpath(xml, unknown, unknown, unknown) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I missing something?

Like the error says - there's no such function. There's one called "xpath" though.

[The manuals are your friend](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-xml.html).